# Laravel create dynamic attribute when doing write in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wonder if it is possible to create or set an attribute when writing in the Model. I tried to do it with a setMutator, but when the attribute is not provided in the list with arguments for a save the value is not created

```
public function setExampleAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['example'] = 100;
}
```

So when I do this:

```
Version::create(['name' => 'mark', 'example' => '50');
```

The record is saved with 100.

But when I do this:

```
Version::create(['name' => 'mark');
```

The record is empty.

Is there a way to do something in between? So before the object is written, add some dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because `create()` uses `fill()` to set attribute values. You can try to use `$attributes` to set default value:

```
protected $attributes = ['example' => 100];
```

If you want to add a dynamic attribute, you can use [Eloquent `creating` event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) inside of which set attribute:

```
$this->attributes['example'] = $value;
```

Or call mutator:

```
$this->setExampleAttribute(null);
```

Comment: I want to make it dynamic, depending on the situation and other variables provided. Hard coded is not option here.

Answer (score 0):

## Override `fill()`

Consider moving this to a base class or a trait, it's just an example:

```php
<?php
class Version extends Model {

  public function fill(array $attributes) {
    parent::fill($attributes);

    // Your own implementation here
  }
}
```

See: [Eloquent Model::fill() source for 5.8](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L318)

Answer (score 0):

In your Version Model:

```
class Version extends Model {
 public function __construct() {
        if(!isset($this->example))$this->example=100;  
    }
}
```